# Determine the cardinality of the set

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone explain the process of determining the cardinality of a set:
which contains the set of positive integers less than 100 which are multiples of 3 or 7.

Comment: The caridinality of "_a_ set
which _contains_ the set of positive integers less than 100 which are multiples of 3 or 7. " can be more or less anything. Surely that's not what the actual problem was! The sensible version of the question asks for the cardinality of the set of positive integers less than 100 which are multiples of 3 or 7.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The cardinality of a finite set is just the number of elements it has. To count this, sum the number of multiples of $3$ under $100$ and the number of multiples of $7$ under $100$, then subtract the number of multiples of $21$ under $100$ (since we counted it twice). This general process is known as the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and is very useful in similar combinatorics problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$
And $|A|=\lfloor \frac{100}{3}\rfloor$

$|B|=\lfloor \frac{100}{7}\rfloor$

$|A\cap B|=\lfloor \frac{100}{21}\rfloor$